# How do I set a start up folder for FastStone Image Viewer?

Tags: software

To distribute photos from a trip abroad to my hosts, I want to include FastStone Image Viewer on the CD with the photos.  I want to set the parent folder for the three folders of images as the Startup Folder, but FastStone stores the entire directory structure of my computer to the image folders where I am building the ISO to burn to CD.  How do I indicate just the image folders on the CD?

Answer (score 1):

Try this tip at the irfanview forum [here](https://irfanview-forum.de/showthread.php?t=2238).

You should use command line parameters :

> irfanview.exe /c:\pics*.* /forcefullscreen

Where `/c:\pics\*.*` points to the pictures folder, and `/forcefullscreen` forces full screen of course.